# Modifying the properties of controls from another thread in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Is it possible to modify the properties of a forms controls from another thread without creating a separate method and delegate for each property that you want to modify?

I am currently writing a multithreaded application where I need background threads to manipulate the userinterface. I feel like the amount of code that I am writing to do simple tasks such as setting a control's text property is huge compared to the code I would write for a single threaded app.

In a single threaded app, one can simply use Control.text = "My Text", but so far when creating a multithreaded application, I need all of the following just to perform the same task in a thread safe way.

```
Delegate Sub ChangeTextDelegate(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal str As String)

Private Sub ChangeText(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal str As String)
    If ctrl.InvokeRequired Then
        ctrl.Invoke(New ChangeTextDelegate(AddressOf ChangeText), New Object() {ctrl, str})
        Return
    End If
    ctrl.Text = str
End Sub
```

I have plenty of similar code that seems equally long for such simple tasks:

```
Delegate Sub ChangeVisibilityDelegate(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal bool As Boolean)

Private Sub ChangeVisibility(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal bool As Boolean)
    If ctrl.InvokeRequired Then
        ctrl.Invoke(New ChangeVisibilityDelegate(AddressOf ChangeVisibility), New Object() {ctrl, bool})
        Return
    End If
    ctrl.Visible = bool
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a lot of unnecessary code with the delegate and the array. The addressof and `{}` syntax's both create instances so you don't need the constructors or declaration leaving you with:

```
Private Sub ChangeVisibility(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal bool As Boolean)
    If ctrl.InvokeRequired Then
        ctrl.Invoke(AddressOf ChangeVisibility, {ctrl, bool})
        Return
    End If
    ctrl.Visible = bool
End Sub
```

This is real actively clean and if your UI is separate from your logic a low overhead. If this is still a problem look to see if you can refactor to groups of ui changes in a single method to accomplish a task rather than invoking a single change. These methods can then be cleanly protected.

Comment: This looks more managable.  Thank you.  Still was hoping for something a bit more concise, but its good to know that the main way to reduce the amount of code is to refactor to groups of changes.  

I'd upvote but apparently you can't even upvote answers to your own question if you are a n00b here :(

Answer (score 1):

After some research on how other languages handle asynchronous functions, I found the following to be an alternative to writing lots of boilerplate code in order to change the properties of controls from a background thread.

The code snippet below uses [lambdas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) (anonymous functions that can be used in the place of delegates) in order to specify functions inline.  This concept is quite common in javascript, but I found that it is also a viable option in VB.NET.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim trd As New Threading.Thread(Sub()
            Invoke(Sub()
                       TextBox1.Visible = False
                   End Sub)
            End Sub)
        trd.IsBackground = True
        trd.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```