# VB.net Print to textbox from another thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have the following code and I am wanting to basically replicate the content  of an ever changing text file and dump it into a text box display, I have the following code but it's not working at the moment.

```
If Not File.Exists(masterPath) Then
            File.Create(masterPath).Dispose()
        End If
        Try
            reader = New StreamReader(chatlog)
        Catch
            File.Create(chatlog)
            bool = False
        End Try
        If bool Then
            'Dim writer As New StreamWriter(masterPath)
            Dim text As String
            Do Until reader.EndOfStream
                text = reader.ReadLine()
                logMenu.AppendText(text & Environment.NewLine)
            Loop
            reader.Close()
            File.Delete(chatlog)
            File.Create(chatlog).Dispose()
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method that uses `Invoke` as needed, like this:

```
Private Sub DisplayLogLine(ByVal text As String)
    If logMenu.InvokeRequired Then
        logMenu.Invoke(AddressOf DisplayLogLine, {text})
        Return
    End If
    logMenu.AppendText(text & Environment.NewLine)
End Sub
```

Then call it with `DisplayLogLine(reader.ReadLine())` in the loop.

<sub>Answer based on quick referencing [Modifying the properties of controls from another thread in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824218/4099598); it's been a while since I wrote multithreaded UI code in .NET.</sub>